# Does cblas_dgemm mutate my input matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, c++, lapack, blas

I have written a matrix class `Matrix<T>` for which I have implemented a wrapper function for `cblas_dgemm`.
`cblas_dgemm` requires to pass my input matrices as `double*`. However, I want my wrapper to work with const Matrices as well (for which I can only provide a `const double*`). Within my call to `cblas_dgemm` I cast the `const` away with `const_cast<double*>`. My question is: Can I rely that `cblas_dgemm` actually only reads my input matrices, so that the const_cast is safe? I know, of course, that eventually the input matrices are the same after the call to `dgemm`, but maybe BLAS does some temporary changes to my matrix?

```
Matrix<double> wrapper_to_cblas(const Matrix<double>&a, const Matrix<double>& b) {
...
cblas_dgemm(/*here I cast const double* to double* */)
...
}
```

Edit: The BLAS implementation I am using actually allows for the use of `const double*`, so it really seems to be implementation-dependent.

Comment: https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dc/d18/cblas__dgemm_8c_source.html

Comment: @Aruralreader There are many BLAS implementations around; just showing that one of them does not mutate inputs does not guarantee that all do. Ideally it should be mentioned in the interface / docs. I can only see it "defined via omission" though; usually it is mentioned when arguments are mutated.

Comment: The hint really was for the OP to look at the code being used.

Comment: @Aruralreader It's not that easy to look at the code being used, though. That's the Blas reference implementation, but in practice if you want good performance you'll be using the more complex [ATLAS](https://github.com/vtjnash/atlas-3.10.0/tree/master/src/blas/gemm), or MKL which is closed-source.

Comment: I checked the BLAS implementation I am using (OpenBLAS) and it actually works fine together with `const double*` so false alarm I guess :)